# Pass the value when a <div> has onclick function and the data inside is changing dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Z4U.png)This is my **index_category.php**.

```
<?php 
include("db.php");
$sql="SELECT * from tcategory";
$conect= mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Failed To Connect.");
while($rows= mysqli_fetch_array($conect, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
    <div class="dialog-outer" data="<?php echo $rows['cat_id']; ?>"  onclick="openNav()">
            <div class="dialog-inner">
            <?php echo $rows['cat_nm'];?>
            </div>
    </div>
<?php } 
?>
```

This is the side nav to which I want to pass the data of **div**

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <h3 class="sub"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><strong> Sub Category</strong></h3>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div id="result">
    <?php include("functions/sub_category.php")?>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    $("#mySidenav").attr("style","width:250px");
    var id=$(".dialog-outer").attr("data");
    alert(id);
    $.post('functions/sub_category.php',{id: id},function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            });
}

function closeNav() {
    $("#mySidenav").attr("style","width:0px");
}
</script>
```

The problem is it is taking `data=1` only but in network it showing as `data=1 data=2 data=3 so on...`
 How to pass all the values from div in `index_category.php` to script in `index.php`

as u can see in the image i want to filter the sub category based on category. But when i click on any of the category it is taking only first value.But when u look in the image(inspect element) it is taking all the values as data=1 data=2 so on...when i click on category i want to get their respective id's.

Comment: Why is your code added twice?

Comment: removed extra coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your your outer nav is repeated, that means that your $(".outer-nav") will return an array of elements not just one. You will need to iterate over them to read their data attributes. If you are looking to get just one specific one I would recommend using JQuery(since you are using it) selector for the click detection and from there working out the .outer-nav that you need.

Sorry if I did not understand your question correctly, but you use a weird mixture of pure JS and JQuery so it is a bit stange to read the code.

Comment: used that jquery for passing value for php so i can use it in my query in where clause. and yeah..i should have used both jquery..thanks...but my problem exist...

Comment: $(".dialog-outer").click(function(){
  $(this).each(function(){
  var id= $(this).attr("data");
  $.post('functions/sub_category.php',{id: id},function(data){
   $('#result').html(data);
  });
  })
 });                                 using this worked like charm..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

as @Aurus told, it is not only one element. You should modify like this:

## ===== 1st method =====

```
.... onclick="openNav(this)">
```

and the function too:

```
function openNav(element) {
    ...
    var id=$(element).attr("data");
    .....
}
```

## ===== 2nd method =====

```
<div class="dialog-outer" data="<?php echo $rows['cat_id']; ?>"  onclick="openNav('oid_<?php echo $rows['cat_id']; ?>')" id="oid_<?php echo $rows['cat_id']; ?>">
```

and the function too:

```
function openNav(id) {
    ...
    var id=$("#"+id).attr("data");
    .....
}
```

Comment: well i tried but it still returning only a first value..thanks for quick response

Comment: I added second method, try that (look at it carefully..)